# Alternative Syntax for Action Links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.net MVC . i am converting the master page which is in web forms to MVC Master Page. But , the CSS for the Menu is designed in such a way that i am not able to use the following syntax:

```
  <li><span><%: Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")%></span></li>
```

I need syntax in the form of

`<a href=""> ..... </a>` .
 I am using aspx view engine. I use Html.ActionLink syntax my CSS would not work and is creating lot of mess.

But, i am in a need of getting exact look and feel as previous application. i am using ASP.net MVC2

Please help..i am not sure whether it is possible or not..

I am not getting redirected to that page by using following syntax:

```
 <a href="/Products/Details/">this prodcut</a>
```

Comment: <li><span><%: Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home",null,new {id= ur product ID})%></span></li>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Url.Action is your friend!**

Using Razor view engine:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" style="" class="" whatever="">My link</a>
```

Using ASPX view engine:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Index", "Home") %>" style="" class="" whatever="">My link</a>
```

Comment: I am using ASP.net mVC 2 .. will it support?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller")">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use

<%: Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")%>

it will render finally into anchor link in the html page. it is not the problem with the tag it is with the css check it thorougly..

to confirm use developer tools in IE.. by clicking on F12, you can understand how the tag is rendering in page.

Regards,
Pavan.g

Comment: I understand its CSS problem..i can not modify CSS now

Comment: The only way you have is to MODIFY the CSS. If you have to get the styles appropriately..

Answer (score 0):

All css will work.

If you have such ActionLink:

```
Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")
```

It generates following Html:

```
<a href="yousite/Home/Index">Index</a>
```

If you want to add class, just write as follows:

```
Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home", null, new {@class="myclass"})
```

It generates following Html:

```
<a class="myclass" href="yousite/Home/Index">Index</a>
```

In MVC it is highly recommended to use `Html.ActionLink`. MVC based on routing. If you change routing, `Html.ActionLink` automatically changes generated link.

Answer (score 0):

To link to an action method in a controller use the following:

```
<a href="/ControllerName/ActionName">...</a>
```

So if you want to access the `Index` method in the `Home` controller, use:

```
<a href="/Home/Index">...</a>
```

You can also add classes using `ActionLink`, e.g.

```
Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Controller", "Action", null, new {@class="css class"})
```

This will produce a link like the following:

```
<a href="/Controller/Action" class="css class">LinkText</a>
```